# Remove the single quotes from join

Tags: magento2, sql, join

I have this magento code :

```
$subquery = new \Zend_Db_Expr('SELECT DISTINCT value from catalog_product_entity_int where  row_id in (select row_id from catalog_product_entity_int where attribute_id = 97 and value = 1)');
$brandCollection->getSelect()->join( array( 't' => '('.$subquery.')' ), 'main_table.brand_id = t.value', array());
```

It generates the following query :

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `prd_brand` 
AS `main_table` 
INNER JOIN `(SELECT DISTINCT value from catalog_product_entity_int where row_id in (select row_id from catalog_product_entity_int where attribute_id = 97 and value = 1))` AS `t` 
ON main_table.brand_id = t.value
```

This query when executing it in phpmyadmin it gives me the following error :

```
Identifier name '(SELECT DISTINCT value from catalog_product_entity_int where row_id in (select row_id from catalog_p' is too long
```

The problem is on the two single quotes between the `SELECT DISTINCT value from...`, when removing them, it passes without any problems and this quotes are generated with the join method.

Is there anyway to bypass those single quotes ?

Comment: sure i will look

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer, it was not due to the join method but it is caused by `'('.$subquery.')'`.
Here is the working code :

```
$subquery = new \Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT DISTINCT value from catalog_product_entity_int where  row_id in (select row_id from catalog_product_entity_int where attribute_id = 97 and value = 1))');
$brandCollection->getSelect()->join( array( 't' => $subquery ), 'main_table.brand_id = t.value', array());
```

Comment: Good, Great news :)